# TwitteR setup_twitter_oauth() gives an error

Tags: r, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using twitteR package for the first time. 
The `setup_twitter_oauth function` gives me an error:

> ```
> [1] "Using browser based authentication"
> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
> Couldn't connect to server
> ```

or

> ```
> [1] "Using browser based authentication" Error in
> init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission =
> self$params$permission, : Bad Request (HTTP 400).
> ```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(twitteR)


setup_twitter_oauth(getOption("twitter_consumer_key"),
                    getOption("twitter_consumer_secret"),
                    getOption("twitter_access_token"),
                    getOption("twitter_access_token_secret"))
```

I am using Rstudio and Windows 7 with a proxy.

Comment: I used `download.file function`to make a test. It seems to work: ` downloaded 823 bytes`

Comment: I see. Did you try the solution in the link I provided? It says you may need to explicitly specify the proxy like `set_config(use_proxy(url='your.proxy.url',port,username,password))`

Comment: I tried to run my code from a computer without proxy. message from R : `[1] "Using browser based authentication" Error in init_oauth1.0(self$endpoint, self$app, permission = self$params$permission,  :   Bad Request (HTTP 400).`

Comment: Wait are you literally passing in those strings instead of using them as placeholders to hide your private data in the question? The arguments to `setup_twitter_oath` are access tokens that Twitter gives you when you register your app. You can't connect with no key / secret / token...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you're literally passing in those strings as arguments to `setup_twitter_oath`. They should be replaced by access tokens that Twitter gives you when you register your app.

You can assign the actual credentials to objects like

`my_key`, `my_secret`, `my_access_token`, `my_access_secret`

and then connect like this:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(my_key, my_secret, my_access_token, my_access_secret)
```

I noticed that if I try to connect with no credential or fake credentials that I get the same error you were experiencing from `setup_twitter_oauth`.

Make sure not to quote those objects or they're considered literal character strings.

Comment: @Wilcar Glad it works! I'd prefer that you'd mark this as the solution to deleting your question, as others may have the same problem and I spent some time figuring this out, but you may certainly do as you like. Cheers.